# Update sql column by adding two fields together

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with several columns.  I need to add data from one column(money) to another column(money) and then update then table row by row.

I have tried select this creates a tempory column but no data gets saved into database

I have tried insert but I need the new total to update into the field that is calculating

I think my solution is an update but so far this is not working for me.

Before update;

```
ID  ColumnNameCurrent   ColumnNameYTD
A               20.20                       89.60 
b               55.00                       147.38
c               60.98                       258.46
d               38.43                     7,894.32
```

After Update (what I hope for)

```
ID  ColumnNameCurrent   ColumnNameYTD
A    20.20                    109.80 
b    55.00                    202.38 
c    60.98                    319.44 
d    38.43                   7,932.75
```

What I think the code should be;

```
UPDATE TableName
SET ColumnNameYTD = ColoumNameYTD + ColumnNameCurrent
```

Can you please explain to me what I can change in the above to get the desired results.

Comment: your two data sets seem identical to me; what am i missing?

Comment: Thanks Pedro  I copied the same table twice instead of the before and after.  I have been looking at this so long I think I have tunnell vision.  Thanks for pointing out and any help would be great.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am missing something with your requirements, your `UPDATE` should work:

```
update yourtable
set ColumnNameYTD = ColumnNameYTD + ColumnNameCurrent
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/053de/1)